# UINavigationController inside of a block

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, objective-c-blocks

I have the following code:

```
[albumButton setAccessoryButtonPressed:^()
             {                                                   
                 [[SoundEffectManager sharedSoundEffectManager] playSoundEffectForKey:kSoundEffectButtonPress];
                 AlbumDetailViewController* detailVC    = [[[AlbumDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AlbumDetailViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];

                 [detailVC setPrice:[albumPrice stringValue]];
                 [detailVC setCoverImage:albumCover];
                 [detailVC setName:albumName];
                 [detailVC setDescription:albumDesc];                                                    
                 [detailVC setProductID:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"com.tunehopper.%@", albumID]];
                 [detailVC setComposer:composer];
                 [detailVC setMaxScore:maxScore];

                 for (NSString* key in songKeys)
                 {
                     NSDictionary*  songDict    = [albumSongs objectForKey:key];
                     NSString*      songTitle   = [songDict objectForKey:@"title"];

                     [[detailVC dataSource] addObject:songTitle];
                 }

                 //UINavigationController *nav = [[self.navigationController parentViewController] navigationController];
                 [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailVC animated:YES];
             }];
```

I want to execute this block from a different viewController.  The only thing not working is the pushViewController.  When I execute the push the AlbumDetailViewController is not called.  I am wondering if the issue I am having has to do with the self.navigationController no longer existing when the block is executed.  I had assumed that the block would use whatever current view controllers navigation controller existed at runtime.  This doesn't seem to be the case. So, does anyone have some pointers on how I can set up the block to actually call the detailViewController at runtime.

Comment: It also depends how you are calling this block. If you are passing it to GCD to run on a background queue it's going to have problems as you are only supposed to call UIKit methods from the main thread.

Answer (score 3):

Putting `self` in a block is... not exactly fraught with peril, but likely to do things you might not expect. Here, `self` is referring to whatever it does in the scope directly outside the block, not the view controller that you have executing the block. Depending on when the block gets executed, it might not have a `navigationController` at that time.

I'd suggest either looking up the navigation controller inside your block a different way (is it the app's root view controller, perhaps?), putting it in a local variable outside the block which you then reference inside, or having the view controller responsible for executing the block pass itself as an argument to the block.